# Make an HTML form element visible only when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have an html form and an element as shown below

is it possible to make the unordered list only visible when someone clicks on the text field. Essentially the ul class "input-requirements" must be hidden unless someone clicks the text field.

Would be ideal if when a user move to a separate element it the unordered list will get hidden again

Is this possible in html , css ?

```html
<label for="username">
  <span>Username</span>
  <input type="text" id="username" minlength="3" required placeholder="ex:-damian98">
  <ul class="input-requirements">
   <li>You must have minimum of 3 characters</li>
   <li>You can only have letters and numbers</li>
   </ul>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. USE CSS selector that will catch the :focus pseudo state at the input level and will advance to the next element (neighbor selector)

1. .input-requirements { display: none} - first hide the list
2. #username:focus + .input-requirements {display: block} - show the list when the input is focussed

RECOMMENDATION: - to learn advanced css selectors )

```css
.input-requirements {
  display: none;
}

#username:focus + .input-requirements {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="username">
  <span>Username</span>
  <input type="text" id="username" minlength="3" required placeholder="ex:-damian98">
  <ul class="input-requirements">
   <li>You must have minimum of 3 characters</li>
   <li>You can only have letters and numbers</li>
   </ul>
</label>
```